# Excel - identify cells with multiple instances of the same values

Tags: excel, formula, criteria

Need to find which cells in column B that contain 3 or more of 21 specific values.

Here are the specific values (each 4 letter string is a single value.) - 
3544
3538
3506
3502
3398
3396
3394
3392
3390
3388
3386
3384
3376
3362
3288
3270
3230
3228
1944
1866
1384

***To clarify more - There are 21 values (within a larger possible group of values) and need to identify the cells which contain 3 or more of those values.**

***Edit 2 - In these single cells (which are all in column B) there are any number of values separated by a comma. The 21 possible values refers to specific values that need to be looked at *within the larger set of values* for 3 or more of the same occurrences. In other words, in these single cells, there will be numbers that are not any of the aforementioned 21 possible values.**

[image]

The "Yes" or "No" would need to go in column C.

Comment: That's all in a *single cell*? (`2212, 2280, 7809, ...`)? Can you split to columns ten just use `COUNTIFS()`?  What have you tried? Also, does your Excel display that all properly? For me, without some messing around, it will try to read that as a single `Number`.

Comment: Yes, the values are in a single cell separated by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula.

With the values you are looking for in `D1:D3`, and your data in `A1`, you can use this:

**EDIT** *added a preceding comma to make the formula more robust*

```
=COUNT(FIND(","&$D$1:$D$3&",",","&A1&","))>=3
```

The formula should be entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula in the formula bar.  Then fill down the formula as far as necessary

**EDIT 2** *If there might be spaces in the cell being tested, try this formula instead to remove those spaces*:

```
=COUNT(FIND(","&$D$1:$D$3&",",","&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")&","))>=3
```

[image]

Comment: Where in this formula would i put the values?
    =COUNT(FIND($D$1:$D$3&",",A1&","))>=3

Comment: @user3697526 If you want to hard code the values, put them in as an array constant instead using the cell reference

Comment: @user3697526 And, in line with your restated requirements, the strings being searched can be any length, and the list of allowable values to search for can be of any size.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand where to put the specific values. These are the values (each 4 digit number is a single value to be searched for) - 3544
3538
3506
3502
3398
3396
3394
3392
3390
3388
3386
3384
3376
3362
3288
3270
3230
3228
1944
1866
1384

Comment: I find it hard to understand why you are having such a problem.  Look at the screenshot in my answer.  Do you see where I placed the "specific values" from your initial example, from before you edited your question to include your REAL values?

Comment: I understand now. Sorry. However, they are all reading as false I think because there is a space after the commas. How would I denote the space in the formula? =COUNT(FIND(", "&$D$1:$D$3&",",","&B1&","))>=3

Comment: @user3697526 I would suggest removing any spaces from the cell being tested.  That way, it won't matter If there are spaces or not.  I will post an example in my answer

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Here is a new version since you changed the requirements

You can use following Module Function:

```
Public Function SplitFind(str As String, values As Range, minoccurs As Integer) As Boolean
    Let parts = Split(str, ",")
    Dim f1, f2, f3 As Boolean
    Dim occurs As Integer
    occurs = 0
    For Each cel In values.Cells
        Let sval = Val(cel.Value)
        Dim found As Boolean
        found = False
        For Each s In parts
            Let n = Val(s)
            If n = sval Then
                found = True
            End If
        Next s
        If found Then
            occurs = occurs + 1
        End If
    Next cel
    SplitFind = occurs >= minoccurs
End Function
```

Now let's say you have the 21 values you are looking for in cells A1 - U1. And the first cell with the comma separated values is in A2.
Then you can use following formula to check if 3 or more of the values in A1-U1 appear in A2:

```
=SplitFind(A2;$A$1:$U$1;3)
```

And here is a guide on how to add custom functions: http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-create-custom-excel-functions/

Comment: Thank you for this, @nharrer. I think my criteria may be a bit different than what you've outlined above. I've edited my question with more specificity.

Comment: Where do you want to have those 21 values? I did put them in 21 cells (here A1:U1). So you can quickly enter and change those 21 values. But if they are always the same we can also put them hard-coded into the function. Other then that the function does what I think you need. It outputs 'true' for a cell (containing the comma separated values) which contains 3 or more values out of the 21. Otherwise 'false'. BTW: I just noticed I had the range in the '=SplitFind(...)' example wrong. Changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine all those special cells are in column A. For my answer, let's imagen your row 1 values `2212,2280,7809,8990,9113,3876` are in cell A1. I would use:

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND("8990";A1;1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("2212";A1;1);0)>0;IFERROR(FIND("7809";A1;1);0)>0);"YES";"NO")
```

I got spanish version of Excel, so i translated the formulas manually, but basically, is 1 **IF** combined with 1 **AND**, and 3 **IFERROR** and 3 **FIND**. The original formula is:

```
=SI(Y(SI.ERROR(ENCONTRAR("8990";A2;1);0)>0;SI.ERROR(ENCONTRAR("2212";A2;1);0)>0;SI.ERROR(ENCONTRAR("7809";A2;1);0)>0);"YES";"NO")
```

And if I record the macro, VBA does it like this (maybe can help you to type it):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(IFERROR(FIND(""8990"",RC[-2],1),0)>0,IFERROR(FIND(""2212"",RC[-2],1),0)>0,IFERROR(FIND(""7809"",RC[-2],1),0)>0),""YES"",""NO"")"
```

Hope this helps. In my Excel it worked perfectly:

[image]

Comment: btw, if you just want to find the rows that matches ANY of the criteria, not all, just change the AND for OR

Comment: I expected the OP to be looking for a way to find the original 3 numbers as well, not only search each row for 3 known numbers.

Comment: So, maybe this makes things more complicated, but i have 21 possible values and need to find the cells which contain 3 or more of those values. Does the above formula work with that?

Comment: But what if it contains numbers like 221288. FIND("2212", ...) would also match those

Comment: You need to adapt the formula then to your needs. If you have 21 possible values and you want this to "activate" if there is 3 or more coincidences, then try to sum all coincidences and if the sum is 3 or more, you got it. Also, about numbers like 221288. FIND("2212", ...) try to limit the indicator to "2212," or something like it.